# Строку в массив

Tags: массивы, php, строки

Всем привет! Помогите преобразовать строку в массив. [Это запрос выдаст саму строку](http://www.micex.ru/marketdata/quotes/info/EQNL/LKOH?lang=en).

Ну или так можно:

```
<?php
     $content_json = file_get_contents('http://www.micex.ru/marketdata/quotes/info/EQNL/LKOH?lang=en');
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какой-то это некорректный JSON. Названия атрибутов без кавычкек, оттого на PHP `json_decode()` не справляется с расшифровкой.

Вот эксперимент, подтверждающий гипотезу. Оставил только начало, где `id` и `title`, и закавычил их:

```
$s = <<<EOF
[{id: "COMMON_SHARE", title: "Тип инструмента"},{id: "SECID", title: "Код ценной бумаги"},{id: "NAME", title: "Полное наименование"},{id: "SHORTNAME", title: "Краткое наименование"},{id: "ISIN", title: "ISIN код"},{id: "REGNUMBER", title: "Номер государственной регистрации"},{id: "ISSUESIZE", title: "Объем выпуска"},{id: "FACEVALUE", title: "Номинальная стоимость"},{id: "FACEUNIT", title: "Валюта номинала"},{id: "ISSUEDATE", title: "Дата начала торгов на ММВБ"},{id: "LATNAME", title: "Английское наименование"}]
EOF;
$s = trim($s);
$s = str_replace(array('id','title'), array('"id"','"title"'), $s);
$result = json_decode($s);
var_dump($result);
```

Этот вариант разобрался `json_decode()`.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, а мот сможете помочь составить регулярное выражение, чтобы убрать лишние символы в строке, а оставить только запяту как разделитель, а содержимое представлять в виде ключ => значение, мот так проще будет, ну всмысле запятой отделять элементы строки, и фуячить их в массив?

Comment: В [аналогичном вопросе](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250815/parsing-json-missing-quotes-on-name) говорят, что можно использовать парсер YAML, а не JSON (который является подчастью YAML). Парсер YAML справляется с такими даными без кавычек вокруг имени. Например, [Symfony YAML component](http://components.symfony-project.org/yaml)

Answer (score 0):

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php).

> (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PECL json >= 1.2.0)
>
> json_decode — Декодирует JSON строку

Answer (score 0):

Вот сам еще кое-что нашел, полезная инфа, мот кому пригодится:

[Как записать массив в файл (PHP)](http://expange.ru/e/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2_%D0%B2_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB_(PHP))